# Error al Conectar Python y SQL Server 2016

Tags: python, sql-server

Necesito conectar python con SQL Server 2016, estuve leyendo y decia que debia de descargar pyodbc, pase a realizarlo y configurar de la manera correcta srgun su servidor y me sale el siguiente error:

> "DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};" pyodbc.InterfaceError:
>   ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][Administrador de controladores ODBC] No
>   se encuentra el nombre del origen de datos y no se especificó ningún
>   controlador predeterminado (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Y mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(
    "DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
    "SERVER = SNMXLAP187\SQLEXPRESS;"
    "DATABASE = prueba;"
    "Trusted_Connection = yes;")

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM IMG')
for data in cursor.fetallO:
    print(data)
```

[image: Esta es ka imagen de como tengo mi sql server]

Comment: tambien ya intente con     "DRIVER={SQL Server};"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

por si alguien mas le pasa, por lo que pude leer en windows todos los datos deben ir pegados sin los espacios , ejem:

```
"DRIVER={SQL Server};" 
"SERVER=SNMXLAP187\SQLEXPRESS;"
"DATABASE=prueba;"
"Trusted_Connection=yes;")
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo me he conectado directamente por medio de una librería llamada [PyMSSQL](http://www.pymssql.org/en/stable/)

Instalación: `python pip install pymssql`

Ejemplo de Uso:

```
import pymssql

query = "SELECT column1, column2,... FROM Table WHERE ..."
conn = pymssql.connect('IP_SERVER', 'domain\user', 'passw', 'DataBase')
cursor = conn.cursor(as_dict=True)
cursor.execute(query)
for row in cursor:
    print(row)
conn.close()
```

[Nota] Al menos con Python 3.7 aparecerá un mensaje DeprecationWarning, sin embargo a pesar de eso, funciona bien. No he probado con otras versiones de python la aparición del mensaje. Es un 'issue' que ya ha sido [reportado y documentado](https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/576). En el siguente commit 2.1.5 estará resuelto ese problema.

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que es por tu driver, descarga el siguiente:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53339

Y crea la conexión de la siguiente manera:

```
spy_conn = pyodbc.connect(
            "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};"
            "SERVER = SNMXLAP187\SQLEXPRESS;"
            "DATABASE = prueba;"
            "Trusted_Connection = yes;")
```

Comment: Ya descargue el driver, pero sigue sin poder conectarse ahora el error es el siguiente:                                                        "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 dor SQL Server};"
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][Administrador de controladores ODBC] No se encuentra el nombre del origen de datos y no se especificó ningún controlador predeterminado (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')                        Si tienes alguna sugerencia te lo agradeceria

Comment: Encontre una solucion por si alguien mas le pasa, por lo que pude leer en windows todos los datos deben ir pegados sin los espacios , ejem:                                                                                 "DRIVER={SQL Server};" "SERVER=SNMXLAP187\SQLEXPRESS;" "DATABASE=prueba;"
"Trusted_Connection=yes;")