# python duplica caracter '\'

Tags: python, sql

Estoy tratando de establecer conexion a sql por python
y me arroja un error donde me duplica el caracter ''

```
driver= '{SQL Server}'
server= '{Servidor}'
uid= '{emp\userA}'
pwd= '{password}'

conn_str = f"driver= {SQL Server};server= {Servidor};UID={uid};PWD={pwd}"
```

y el error que me arroja es "SQL SERVER LOGIN FAILED FOR USER 'emp\\userA'"

Notese que en el error me muestra que duplico la contrabarra. Como puedo evitarlo?
Gracias!

Comment: por favor incluye el código que estás ejecutando, la expresión `'{emp\userA}'` genera un error, y las expresiones del format string tampoco son correctas.

Comment: ¿Estás usando pyodbc o pymssql? En cualquier caso, la conexión está mal. Mira [este ejemplo](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/python/windows/step/2.html) oficial. Mira también [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/278416/80870) y sus respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

Primero, no está duplicando la "\". El string contiene sólo una "\". El detalle es que Python te la muestra como "\\" para destacar el hecho de que hay una barra en el string y no una secuencia de escape.

¿Confuso? Si. Horrible.

El backslah "\" se usa para indicar una secuencia de escape en Python y casi todos los lenguajes de programación.

Secuencias de escape comunes son `\n` (nueva línea), `\r` (carriage return), `\t` (tabulación), etc.

Para evitar que Python interprete los "\" como señal de secuencia de escape tienes dos alternativas:

1. Anteponer una "r" delante del string. Esta "r" evita que Python interprete cualquier "" dentro del string. Tu código quedaría así: `uid= r'{emp\userA}'`.
2. "Escapar" el "\\" anteponiendo otro "\". El código queda así: `uid= '{emp\\userA}'`.

Observación. Me parece que estás tratando de usar "f-string", en cuyo caso te faltaría una "f" delante de cada string. Con la "f" consigues reemplazar las expresiones entre "{}" por su correspondiente valor.

Comment: Primero gracias por la respuesta. Ya intente con la R y escapandolo, pero no. Y lo ultimo que me pusiste sobre el f-string, no me quedo claro donde deberia anteponer las f.

Probe uid= r'{emp\userA}' e hice un print y me lo imprime correctamente emp\userA
el problema es que cuando pasa la credencial a SQL, me lo duplica ahi me parece!

Comment: Parece que SQL a su vez interpreta el "\" como secuencia de escape. SQL no es mi área.